# awk is not printing column headers

Tags: csv, unix, awk

I am very new to awk so I am sure I am screwing up somehow, but I am just not sure how.

I am trying to parse through a tsv file to only print certain columns.

Here is the entirety of my code below:

```
#!/bin/sh

today=$(date "+%m.%d.%y") # date is the command to get today's date, and the "+%m_%d_%y" will print it in month_day_year format

for i in *_checkm_qa_11.21.20.tsv;
do
    SAMPLE=$(echo ${i} | sed "s/_checkm_qa_11.21.20.tsv//")
    echo ${SAMPLE} "parsing CheckM results"
    
    awk -F ' ' 'BEGIN {OFS="\t"; printf "%s %s %s %s %s %s\n", "Bin_ID", "Marker_Lineage", "Lineage_ID", "Genome_Num", "Completeness", "Contamination"} NR > 1 {if ($6 >=50 && $7 <= 99) print $0;}' ${i} > temp.txt
    
    cat temp.txt | sed 's/ /\t/g' | tr -d "(" | tr -d ")" | cut -f 1,2,3,4,7,8 > ${SAMPLE}_QA_best.tsv
    rm temp.txt
done
```

For whatever reason, my output file is not printing all of the column headers. This is what it looks like:

```
Bin_ID  Marker_Lineage  Lineage_ID  Genome_Num
EA_Pool-SeaWater_1-1a_S26_contigs.fasta.metabat-bins-_-t_4_-m_1500.10   c__Gammaproteobacteria  UID4267 119 85.58   2.06
EA_Pool-SeaWater_1-1a_S26_contigs.fasta.metabat-bins-_-t_4_-m_1500.11   f__Rhodobacteraceae UID3340 84  68.18   0.76
```

Can someone tell me why thel ast two columns I call for (Completeness and Contamination) are not appearing? I am skipping the first line of my input file and replacing it with column headers I describe in the awk command. I have tried `printf "%s %s %s %s %s %s\n"`, `printf "%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s\n"`, and `printf "%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\n"`.

I am just not sure where I am going wrong, and anyone's insight would help. Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to SO. Good that you have shown your efforts in your question. Could you please post your input and expected output more clearly in your question for better understanding of your question.

Comment: i think because `cut -f 1,2,3,4,7,8` your column headers in 5,6 index

Comment: try to reduce the bash script to the portion that is failing, search online help on how to debug a bash script. Once you have pinpointed the issue, if that issue is still [tag:awk] related, trim your code down to the faulty call AND add the input text of the script to your question.